# Close file without quitting VIM application?

Tags: vim

I use the `:e` and `:w` commands to edit and to write a file. I am not sure if there is "close" command to close the current file without leaving Vim?

I know that the `:q` command can be used to close a file, but if it is the last file, Vim is closed as well; Actually on Mac OS MacVim does quit. Only the Vim window is closed and I could use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to open a blank Vim window again. I would like Vim to remain open with a blank screen.

Answer (score 397, accepted):

This deletes the buffer (which translates to close the file)

```
:bd
```

Comment: Yours is better than mine for what the OP asked, although I tend to prefer :enew because I like having the buffer in the buffer list. :)

Comment: When I do this, vim shows the first buffer, but I can still access the buffer

Comment: @Martin, to completely delete the buffer, use **:bw**

Answer (score 54):

As already mentioned, you're looking for `:bd`, however this doesn't completely remove the buffer, it's still accessible:

```
:e foo
:e bar
:buffers
  1 #h   "foo"                          line 1
  2 %a   "bar"                          line 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
:bd 2
:buffers
  1 %a   "foo"                          line 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue
:b 2
2   bar
```

You may instead want `:bw` which completely removes it.

```
:bw 2
:b 2 
E86: Buffer 2 does not exist
```

Not knowing about `:bw` bugged me for quite a while.

Comment: Just keep in mind that VIM's help says this about `:bw` -- "Don't use this unless you know what you are doing."

Answer (score 24):

If you have multiple split windows in your Vim window then `:bd` closes the split window of the current file, so I like to use something a little more advanced:

```
map fc <Esc>:call CleanClose(1)

map fq <Esc>:call CleanClose(0)


function! CleanClose(tosave)
if (a:tosave == 1)
    w!
endif
let todelbufNr = bufnr("%")
let newbufNr = bufnr("#")
if ((newbufNr != -1) && (newbufNr != todelbufNr) && buflisted(newbufNr))
    exe "b".newbufNr
else
    bnext
endif

if (bufnr("%") == todelbufNr)
    new
endif
exe "bd".todelbufNr
endfunction
```

Comment: Now what this snippet does?

Comment: You probably want <CR> after the calls to actually execute the command.

Comment: @dolzenko it maps 'fc' and 'fq' in normal mode to optionally save the current buffer then switch to a new buffer before deleting the original. This preserves any splits you have set up.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. When I try it, though, I get the following error message: "Cannot redefine function CleanClose: It is in use"

Comment: n00b here. should I just paste this into .vimrc? Doing that doesn't seem to work for me. if I type `:fc` it just says `E492: Not an editor command: fc`.

Comment: Ok typing it without `:` worked :) It only puts `call CleanClose(0)` on the command line though, still have to hit Enter for it to go. How do I make `fc` just run the command without needing that extra Enter?

Comment: Don't remap "f" . . . "f" is actually super useful. With this mapping, you can never "find" forward for "c" or "q."

Answer (score 18):

```
:[N]bd[elete][!]                        *:bd* *:bdel* *:bdelete* *E516*
:bd[elete][!] [N]
                Unload buffer [N] (default: current buffer) and delete it from
                the buffer list.  If the buffer was changed, this fails,
                unless when [!] is specified, in which case changes are lost.
                The file remains unaffected.  Any windows for this buffer are
                closed.  If buffer [N] is the current buffer, another buffer
                will be displayed instead.  This is the most recent entry in
                the jump list that points into a loaded buffer.
                Actually, the buffer isn't completely deleted, it is removed
                from the buffer list |unlisted-buffer| and option values,
                variables and mappings/abbreviations for the buffer are
                cleared.
```

Answer (score 11):

If you've saved the last file already, then `:enew` is your friend (`:enew!` if you don't want to save the last file). Note that the original file will still be in your buffer list (the one accessible via `:ls`).

Answer (score 8):

If you *modify* a file and want to close it without quitting Vim and without saving, you should type `:bd!`.

Answer (score 4):

`:bd` can be mapped. I map it to <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> if I need to force-close because of some change I no longer want.

Answer (score 4):

The [bufkill.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1147) plugin adds `BD` etc., to delete the buffer without closing any splits (as `bd`) would alone.

Answer (score 3):

Insert the following in your .vimrc file and, with pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>, it will close the current file.

```
:map <F4> :bd<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Butane plugin](https://github.com/Soares/butane.vim) to keep the window layout when closing a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

For me [close-buffers](https://github.com/Asheq/close-buffers.vim) is pretty useful plugin:

`:Bdelete this` to close that you can remap.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue so I made the plugin.
This plugin replace :q and other commands and then prevent the window closed.

if you still have issue, please try to use following plugin. 
https://github.com/taka-vagyok/prevent-win-closed.vim