# Why might Vim quit when the ‘:bdelete’ command is run?

Tags: vim

According to the [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256204/vim-close-file-without-quiting-vim-application), the `:bd` command should not quit Vim (gVim) when it is the last buffer remaining. Unfortunately, it does close gVim in my case. Did I understand something wrong about `:bd`?

I am also using a preconfigured [vimrc](https://gist.github.com/939194)  file. Maybe a setting in there has that side affect, but I couldn’t find it.

Comment: I tried your .vimrc and I don't have the same issue. It must be something else that's causing it.

Comment: Thanks for trying my vimrc. As ZyX mentioned it seems that it is a problem with some plugin. I posted the output of his recommended command under his answer.

Comment: I'm really curious what plugin was causing this. As I'd like to actually _have_ this functionality.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
:set eventignore=all | bd | set eventignore=
```

If this won't quit vim then you have some plugin that defines an autocommand that quits vim when no more buffers are present in the list, so after that try doing

```
verbose autocmd BufWinLeave,BufLeave,BufDelete,BufUnload,BufWipeout
```

This will show you all autocommands attached to given events (these are events that are executed when buffer is deleted) and where they were defined. Note that I do not have any autocommands attached to these events that are defined by plugins in standart vim distribution.

**Update:** I do not see anything bad in your output. You may also try

```
verbose autocmd BufNew,BufAdd,BufCreate,BufEnter,BufWinEnter
```

(because when you leave last buffer new empty one is created). If this does not show anything suspicious, start ignoring event types: if you are on linux try the following script:

```
for event in BufWinLeave BufLeave BufDelete BufUnload BufWipeout BufNew BufAdd BufCreate BufEnter BufWinEnter
do
    event=$event vim file -c "set eventignore=$event | bd"
done
```

This script should iterate until you find event name that causes trouble. After this you can use `execute "verbose autocmd" $event` in vim to narrow number of plugins that should be checked. After you got list of autocmd groups (augroup names are shown just before event name in your output: `railsPluginDetect` is one of such groups), delete events in them (`augroup {GroupName} | execute 'autocmd!' | augroup END`) and find out which plugin to claim.

Alternatively, you can use debugger:

```
debug bd
```

, then `s<CR>n<CR><CR><CR>...` until vim quits; don't forget to remember what vim have shown above `>` prompt before quiting.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Indeed it seems that a plugin does this. I run the verbose command as you recommended and got this result: https://gist.github.com/939432 Do you have an idea which of those plugins causes it and how to overwrite it again?

Comment: Not sure what solved the problem, but it doesn't occur anymore. If it comes up again, I will leave a comment what plugin caused it. Thanks for the help.